# How can one bend Android's layout XML l10n-wise?

Tags: android, android-layout, localization, mozilla, android-xml

As you probably know, Mozilla aims to do the mobile UI on fennec as native Java/Android UI.

That includes using the layout XML files, which by default use stuff like

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/text_a"
    />
```

with `@string/text_a` being resolved to `text_a` in a `strings.xml` file, doing l10n.

We'd like to use something else, and I wonder if/how we can hook that up in the XML files.

So, I'd love to get pointers to android source code that actually does the string lookup, for one.

And I have three ideas on how to hook up something custom, which are not fact-checked, basically because I haven't managed to find the code that does stuff yet:

1. `@moz-l10n/text_a`, with a java-implemented service giving back values for that resource type
2. `moz:l10n="text_a"` custom attribute that would get hooked up to post process the generated widgets
3. subclass the widgets we want to localize with our scheme, adding (2)

I hope that there are folks out here that have a good idea to point me to good paths or shoot some down.

PS: I'd appreciate a lack of bike-shed about whether android l10n scheme is good or not.

Answer (score 2):

> So, I'd love to get pointers to android source code that actually does the string lookup, for one.

`android.content.res.Resources` delegates to `android.content.res.AssetManager` and the `getResourceText()` method. That in turn dives into a native `loadResourceValue()` method. And you're on your own from there... :-)

> 1) @moz-l10n/text_a, with a java-implemented service giving back values for that resource type

Unless you are going to pre-process your faux resource files with your own build tools, generating valid Android resource files into the `res/` directory, you cannot invent new resource types (e.g., `@moz-10n`). That would require modifications to the build tools and the firmware.

> 2) moz:l10n="text_a" custom attribute that would get hooked up to post process the generated widgets
>
> 3) subclass the widgets we want to localize with our scheme, adding 2)

Your option #3 is definitely possible and is fairly typical when creating custom widgets. It's conceivable that the techniques for it (usually involving a `res/values/attrs.xml` file with a `declare-styleable` resource) could somehow be applied to a standard widget class, but I've never seen that done. Of course, you could always do the pre-processing as in how you'd accomplish option #1.